# Assigning a finite number, $n(G)$, to a finite group $G$ with this property

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I want to assign a finite number, $n(G)$, to a finite group $G$ such that if $H$ is a proper retract of $G$, then $n(H)\lneq n(G)$. By a retract of $G$, I mean a subgroup $H$ of $G$ for which there is an epimorphism $r:G\to H$ such that $r(x)=x$ for all $x\in H$. By a proper retract, I mean a retract $H$ such that $H\neq G$.

I want that this number depends on the group properties of $G$. So the cardinality of $G$ is not a good idea for me. I think $n(G)$ will be in such a way that if $G$ is a finite abelian group, then it coincides with the number of non-zero direct summands of $G$. (In fact, if $G$ is a finite abelian group and $H$ is a proper retract of it (which is a direct summand and vice versa), then by the fundamental theorem of finitely generated  abelian groups we get that the number of direct summands of $H$ is less than the number of direct summands of $G$.)

**My idea**: If $H$ is a retract of $G$, then $G=H\ltimes N$, where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. For example, $S_2 =\mathbb{Z}_2\ltimes \mathbb{Z}_3$. I can say that $n(S_3)=2$; I mean the number of semidirect summands (both normal and non-normal ones). But I don't how to define it for bigger groups.

Comment: The length of a chief series of $G$ would work, but that is still too crude for abelian groups. Perhaps something like the maximum length of a normal series of $G$ in which all subgroups are complemented?

Comment: @DerekHolt That is a good idea. Could you please guide me how to prove that this number satisfies $n(H)\lneq n(G)$?

Comment: @DerekHolt Is "normal" necessary? Retracts are not necessarily normal. Their complement are normal.

Comment: If $H$ is a proper retract of $G$, then $H$ has a normal complement $N$ in $G$. So there is a complemented normal series of $G$ that includes $N$ together with the subgroups $NH_i$, where $H_i$ is a complemented normal series of $H$. So we get $n(G) \ge n(H)+1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you very much for your help. I understood you comment in this way: ‎Assume that ‎‎$‎‎H=H_0 >H_1 >‎\cdots ‎>H_{n(H)}=1‎$ is a complemented normal series of ‎$‎‎H$ ‎with ‎the‎ ‎maximum ‎length ‎$‎‎n(H)$.‎ Since ‎‎$‎‎H$ ‎is a‎ ‎proper ‎retract ‎of ‎‎$‎‎G$, ‎‎it has a normal complement ‎$‎‎N$‎ in ‎$‎‎G$. ‎Then ‎ $G=G_0=N‎‎H=NH_0 >NH_1 >‎\cdots ‎>NH_{n(H)}=N>1‎$ is a complemented normal series of ‎$‎‎G$. and so ‎$n(G)\geq n(H)+1‎‎$.‎

Comment: @DerekHolt But the term $NH_i$ have complement in $G$? How can we use this fact that the term $H_i$ have complement in $H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have another related question: Can we use a subgroup series (necessarily not normal not subnormal) of $G$ in which all subgroups are retracts of $G$ (or equivalently, all subgroups have normal complement in $G$) instead of saying that a normal series of $G$ in which all subgroups are complemented? Are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: @DerekHolt My problem is: If $G=H_1 \ltimes N_1=H_2 \ltimes N_2$, then I can't prove that $H_1 \subset H_2$ implies that $N_2 \subset N_1$.

Comment: To answer your first question, a complement $C$ of $H_i$ in $H$ is a complement of $NH_i$ in $G$, because $NH_iC = NH = G$ and $NH_i \cap C \le H \cap C = 1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt You are right. Thanks very much. My second question comes from this fact that we can work with retracts easier than normal subsgroups which have complement. For example, if we want to use the above definition for free groups of finite rank, we can easily see that every retract of free group of rank $r$ is a free group of rank $s\leq r$. While we don't say this for a normal subgroup that has complement by your answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288959/free-group-as-semi-direct-product .

Comment: I think your definition is equivalent i.e. it gives the same value for $n(G)$, but I don't agree that it is easier to work with. I prefer the complemented normal series version! I will answer the question properly when I have time.

Comment: @DerekHolt I understood. I really appreaicte your help.

Comment: The trivial way is to define inductively $n(1)=0$ and $n(G)=1+\max n(H)$ where $H$ ranges over proper retracts of $G$ (and this provides the smallest possible such function $n$). The only problem is then to estimate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said yourself, you could define $n(G) = |G|$, but you are not happy with that. I am guessing that you would like $n(G)$ to be as small as possible. The length of a chief series of $G$ would also work, and would be an improvement on $|G|$, but we can do better than that.

I propose to define $n(G)$ to be the maximum length of a strict splitting normal series of $G$.

To be more precise, a normal series for $G$ is a series $1 \le N_1 \le N_2 \le \cdots \le N_k = G$ in which each $N_i$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, it is strict if all of the inclusions are strict, and splitting if each $N_i$ has a complement in $G$.

If $H$ is a proper retract of $G$ then it has a nontrivial normal complement $N$ in $G$ and then (as discussed in the comments) if $1 < H_1 < \cdots < H_{n(H)} = H$ is a maximum length strict splitting normal series of $H$, then $1 < N < NH_1 < \cdots< NH_{n(H)} = G$ is a splitting normal series for $G$, so we get $n(G) \ge n(H)+1$, and the function $n(G)$ has the required property.

Note that this function gives the optimal answer for abelian groups of the number of direct factors in a conical decomposition.

You proposed an alternative definition $n'(G)$ as the maximum length of a strict series $1 <H_1 < H_2 < \cdots < H_k=G$ of subgroups in which each $H_i$ with $i < k$ is a proper retract of $G$. That would also work, and I claim that $n'(G)=n(G)$.

It is easy to see that a strict splitting normal series gives rise to a strict series of proper retracts, so we get $n(G) \le n'(G)$.

It is less clear that a strict series $1 =H_k < H_{k-1} < \cdots < H_1 < H_0=G$ of proper retracts gives rise to a strict splitting normal series, but we can see that as follows.

Let $N_i$ be a normal complement of $H_i$ in $G$. We do not necessarily have $N_i < N_{i+1}$, but we can redefine the $N_i$ to get that property. Since $H_2 < H_1$ and $G=H_2N_2$, we get $H_1 = H_2(N_2 \cap H_1)$. Then $N_1(N_2 \cap H_1)$ is also a normal complement of $H_2$ in $G$, so we can redefine $N_2 = N_1(N_2 \cap H_1)$, etc.

Hence $n'(G) \ge n(G)$ and we have $n(G)=n'(G)$ as claimed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice answer and help. I've learned good points from your comments and answer. Appreciate it.

Comment: Dear @DerekHolt , is the proof of this statement "It is easy to see that a strict splitting normal series gives rise to a strict series of proper retracts" similar to what you proved about "a strict series of proper retracts gives rise to a strict splitting normal series"?

Comment: I am really sorry to ask so many questions. Just my last question is: Why do you prefer the complemented normal series version?

Comment: @DerekHolt Is $N_1 (N_2 \cap H_1)$ normal in $G$?

Comment: Yes, it is normal in $G$. I guess I prefer the splitting chief series definition because it does not explicitly mention retracts, but since it is equivalen to your definition it doesn't matter much.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you very much. I got it. Could you please tell me whether the proof of this statement "It is easy to see that a strict splitting normal series gives rise to a strict series of proper retracts" similar to what you proved about "a strict series of proper retracts gives rise to a strict splitting normal series"? because you wrote "It is easy to see ..." but I couldn't prove it directly.