# Assigning a finite number, $n(G)$, to an elementary amenable group $G$ with $\operatorname{cd}G<\infty$

Tags: gr.group-theory

*Elementary amenable groups* is the smallest class of groups that contains all abelian and all finite groups, and is closed under extensions and directed unions. The *Hirsch length*, $h(G)$, of an elementary amenable group is finite and equal to $n\geq 0$, if $G$ has a series $1=H_0 \lhd \cdots \lhd H_r =G$ in which the factors are either locally finite or infinite cyclic, and exactly $n$ factors are infinite cyclic. In all other cases, $h(G)=\infty$.

I want to assign a finite number, $n(G)$, to an finitely generated elementary amenable group $G$ such that if $H$ is a proper retract of $G$, then $n(H)\lneq n(G)$. By a retract of $G$, I mean a subgroup $H$ of $G$ for which there is an epimorphism $r:G\to H$ such that $r(x)=x$ for all $x\in H$. By a proper retract, I mean a retract $H$ such that $H\neq G$.

I asked a similar question for finite groups here: [Assigning a finite number, $n(G)$, to a finite group $G$ with this property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447303/assigning-a-finite-number-ng-to-a-finite-group-g-with-this-property) . Dear @DerekHolt proposed there to define $n(G)$  to be the maximum length of a strict splitting normal series of $G$ (to be more precise, a normal series for $G$ is a series $1 \le N_1 \le N_2 \le \cdots \le N_k = G$ in which each $N_i$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, it is strict if all of the inclusions are strict, and splitting if each $N_i$ has a complement in $G$). I proposed an alternative definition $n'(G)$ as the maximum length of a strict series $1 <H_1 < H_2 < \cdots < H_k=G$ of subgroups in which each $H_i$ with $i < k$ is a retract of $G$. It turned out that $n'(G)=n(G)$.

By a cohomlogical dimension of a group $G$ I mean $\operatorname{cd}G=\sup \{n\;\text{such that}\; H^n (G,M)\neq 0,\; \text{for some}\; \mathbb{Z}G\text{-module}\; M\}$). By the following argument, $n(G)<\infty$ for a countable elementary amenable group $G$ with $\operatorname{cd}G<\infty$:

Let $G$ be a finitely generated countable elementary amenable group with $cdG<\infty$. Since $\operatorname{cd}G<\infty$, then $h(G)<\infty$. Let $M_i$ be the kernel of the retraction $r_i:G_{i-1}\to G_i$. Then $h(G_{i-1})=h(M_i)+h(G_i)$ for $i=1,2,\ldots$. Thus, $h(G)=h(M_1)+h(M_2)+\cdots +h(M_i)+h(G_i)$. Hence, there exists an integer $k$ such that $h(M_i)=0$ for all $i$ except no more that $k$. Then $M_i=1$ for such $i$. Therefore, we get immediately that $G_i=G_{i-1}$ for these $i$. Then $n(G)<\infty$.

Now my question is that: Can we determine $n(G)$ in terms of $h(G)$ or $\operatorname{cd}G$ precisely (or in terms of other group properties of $G$)? Is $n(G)=h(G)+1$?

Comment: There exists no such assignment, just because there exists an elementary amenable group $G$ that is isomorphic to a proper retract of itself (e.g., a free abelian group of infinite countable rank).

Comment: @YCor Sorry, you are right but I meant finitely generated elementary amenable groups.

Comment: It is still not true that a finitely generated EA group has finite $h$ or cd. For instance, the wreath product $\mathbf{Z}\wr\mathbf{Z}$ is finitely generated solvable, but has a free abelian subgroup of infinite rank. So it has infinite Hirsch rank and infinite cohomological dimension.

Comment: Dear @YCor I don't want to prove a finitely generated EA group has finite h or cd. This is my assumption. My question was that if $G$ is a finitely generated countable elementary amenable group with $cdG<\infty$, then $n(G)=h(G)$.

Comment: But this is what you wrote "Let $G$ be a finitely generated countable elementary amenable group. Since $\operatorname{cd}G<\infty$, then $h(G)<\infty$." If it's an assumption, reformulate.

Comment: @YCor Sorry, you are right. Consider it done.

Comment: The number $n(G)$ is not uniquely defined. However, it might be defined as $1+\sup n(H)$ where $H$ ranges over proper retracts (with $n(1)=0$), and then this is the smallest such function. With this definition $n(\mathbf{Z}^d)=d$. But, for a nontrivial $\mathbf{Q}$-irreducible action, $n(\mathbf{Z}^2\rtimes\mathbf{Z})=2$ (while Hirsch length is 3).

Comment: @YCor Could you please tell me why $n(G)$ is not uniquely definied?

Comment: @YCor You definition is nice and similar to the definition of the capacity of compacta defined by K. Borsuk. Thanks very much for this good suggestion.

Comment: You wrote axioms for a function $n(G)$. There is not a unique function $n$ satisfying the axioms. For instance, if $n$ satisfies the axioms, then so is $1+n$. (You're by the way a bit vague on whether you mean $n$ to be integral-valued.) The function I defined is of course uniquely defined. It is well-defined because the Hirsch length decreases when passing to a proper retract (because the group is torsion-free, the kernel has positive Hirsch length), and indeed satisfies $n(G)\le h(G)$.

Comment: @YCor Understood completely. Thank you. Is $n(G)$ (by your definition)  related to the length of a chain proepr retracts? I mean does it coincide with the maximum length of sequences of proper retracts of a group $G$?

Comment: Probably not, because a retract of a retract need not be a retract.

Comment: @YCor I defined $n'(G)$ as the maximum length of a strict series $1 <H_1 < H_2 < \cdots < H_k=G$ of subgroups in which each $H_i$ with $i < k$ is a retract of $G$. When $H_1$ is a retract of $G$, trivially is a retract of $H_i$, for all $i\geq 1$. As you said, your $n(G)$ is the smallest such function. So $n(G)\leq n'(G)$. On other hand, if $n'(G)<\infty$, then $n'(G)\leq n(G)$.

Comment: @YCor The reason is that: if  $1 <H_1 < H_2 < \cdots < H_{n'(G)}=G$ is a strict series of retracts of $G$ with maximum lentgh, then $n(H_1)\geq 1$, $n(H_2)\geq 1+n(H_1)=2$, and finally $n(G)\geq 1+n'(G)-1=n'(G)$. Thus, $n(G)=n'(G)$.

Comment: Dear @YCor , Could you please tell me why $n(G)=1+\sup n(H)$ (that you defined) is the smallest such function? I could'nt prove it.

Comment: @YCor Could you please tell why  $n(G)$ you defined is the  smallest such function? I could'nt prove it.